# Rails unit test not loading fixtures

Tags: unit-testing

When I run `bundle exec rake test` there is a foreign key error when it tries to insert a row:

```
UserPreferencesControllerTest#test_should_create_user_preference:
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "user_preferences" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_d9451c7b48"
DETAIL:  Key (sport_id)=(1) is not present in table "sports".
: INSERT INTO "user_preferences" ("skill_level", "notes", "user_id", "sport_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
    app/controllers/user_preferences_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
    app/controllers/user_preferences_controller.rb:29:in `create'
    test/controllers/user_preferences_controller_test.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserPreferencesControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/user_preferences_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:UserPreferencesControllerTest>'
```

It looks like there is no 'sports' fixture having an id of 1.

However, the fixture exists in test/fixtures/sports.yml, like this:

```
--- {}

basketball:
  id: '1'
  name: "basketball"
  description: "game with a large bouncy ball"
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of sports.yml declares the sports fixtures to be an empty set: `{}`. Replace the first line with `---` rather than `--- {}`